# White space PHP explosion concatenation

Tags: php, file

I have 3 variables I'm trying to explode on from AJAX. One is a concatenation.

**I tried this first**

```
   $XFiles = explode(",".$fileName." && ".$fileID, $row['filename']); //Dosnt Work
   $XFiles = explode(",".$fileName."&&".$fileID, $row['filename']); //Dosnt Work
   $XFiles = explode(",".$fileName." &&".$fileID, $row['filename']); //Dosnt Work
   $XFiles = explode(",".$fileName."&& ".$fileID, $row['filename']); // Works?

       //Set $row to $filesBunch = $row['filename'];
```

Many instances of filename in `filebunch`:

```
$fileID = $_POST['ID'];
$fileName = $_POST['fileName'];
```

I have 2 variables I'm trying to explode on BUT one needs concatenation.

The comparison between the 2 records must adhere to X format - img.jpg && 2

```
$newfileName = ",".$fileName."&&".$fileID;

$XFiles = explode($newfileName,$filesBunch);

echo $XFiles[0];  //Case whichever doesnt function
```

But, if I arrange the code with a white space after the second `&&` it works?
I'm not sure why? There are no current examples. I can't find and the data. I've found on whitespace markup says periods equal 1 whitespace AND the PHP code eliminates white spaces between double quotes. Please help, thank you.

```
$newfileName = ",".$fileName."&& ".$fileID;
$XFiles = explode($newfileName,$filesBunch);
echo $XFiles[0/1];  //Works?
```

Comment: Minor Changes to make it more readable.

Comment: Whether your code works or not depends entirely on the values of the different variables. You haven't shared anything about that.